# How to organize objects inside redux with Immutablejs & read in react native to use in flatlist

Tags: react-native, redux, immutable.js

I'm new to react native & redux, I have been experimenting a lot and almost have a working app. I have one question on how to organize the data inside redux which would help performance wise when parsing with Listview / Flatlist in react native.

Below is structure of data that I receive from my api.

```
    const data = {
         "abcd1": {
           "id":"abcd1",
           "title": "test",
           "contentOrder": 2
         },
         "abcd2": {
           "id":"abcd2",
           "title": "test2", 
           "contentOrder": 1
         }
    }
```

Convert to Immutablemap

```
    const sortedMap = new Immutable.OrderedMap(data).sortBy((item) => item.contentOrder)
```

Reducer merge

```
case ActionTypes.FETCH_SECTION.SUCCESS:
    return state.merge({
        isFetching: false,
        result: action.response,
        error: ""
    })
```

I'm changing this to an immutablemap using Immutablejs and pushing to redux store. Now when I want to read the items from state for displaying in Flatlist or ListView, 
the only option I see is to create an array with all the items like

```
    let newsItem = []
    state.get("data").valueSeq().forEach((val, index) => {
        newsItem.push(val)
    });

    and use it like this inside the component

    <FlatList
        data={newsItem}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        renderItem={this._renderRow}
    />
```

So my question, is this a good practise ? or is there a better implementation that I'm missing.

I also have to add infinite scrolling, for this I'm planning to call my action  "onEndReached" to merge the store with the new data from Api.

I want to implement this in proper way to avoid any performance bottleneck, hence please advise.

Thanks for your advise & help

Answer (score 0):

Usually reducing the computation time is done by trying to eliminate computation altogether.

This is often done by a library like [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect)
which helps you store the minimum state inside of the redux store.
Those are the two first introduction line from the github page:

> Selectors can compute derived data, allowing Redux to store the
>   minimal possible state. Selectors are efficient. A selector is not
>   recomputed unless one of its arguments change.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm using reselect to get the data from redux store. Could you let me know if the above mentioned way of converting from immutablemap to list is good idea ? It looks like I'm doing some additional steps to convert the map to list just to pass it to FlatList - I suppose there is a better way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

`OrderedMap` has a `toArray()` method so the way it could be passed to a `FlatList` is:

```js
<FlatList
    data={this.props.albums.toArray()}
    keyExtractor={item => item[0]}
    renderItem={({item}) => this.renderRow(item[1])}
/>
```

A little explanation, calling `toArray()` method on an `OrderedList` returns an array of arrays i.e. `[[k1, v1], [k2, v2], [k3, v3]]` so `item` in the `FlatList` is one of `[k, v]` thefore in `keyExtrator` the key is passed via `item[0]` and in `renderItem` the value is passed via `item[1]`.